# How can I selectively highlight or style bus lines, subway lines, etc. with Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

#### Attempt 1

First, I figured using [TransitLater](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-transit), but this shows *all* transit at once. I need to selectively toggle between subways, streetcars, busses; showing only one at a time.

#### Attempt 2

Next I figured I could simply bring up the Transit Layer, and style whichever one I want to highlight using the [javascript styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling), but it doesn't look like it's possible to style the transit layer.

I would like to, for example, be able to style all subway lines green.

I considered polylines, but I haven't found a decent polyline editing tool... there's the [Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility), but it doesn't display the transit layer that I need to trace.

Baiscally the client wants to be able to toggle on the map to selectively show bus lines, subways lines, highways, and streetcar lines.

So either I need to be able to style those, or I need a decent polyline editor so I can draw them by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked in your question is probably exhaustive.

Here is a list of all currently styleable "Feature types" from this documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType

Subways don't appear there (yet). But styled maps is getting trendy, so there's a good chance that Google will increase that list. But if you want to be sure to be able to meet your needs you will probably have to buy some vector data from your local map vector data retailer and show it yourself on the map.

Comment: from those docs, you can style trains and highways, but not subway / streetcar lines.

Comment: That's what I meant but I forgot to mention it, to focused on making my point. It's not on the API yet. It may be in the future. It may not be. The only trustable way for you then is to get the vector data somewhere and add it on the map.